# HDD not detected anymore after ubuntu update and restart

Tags: boot, updates, hard-drive, update-manager, hardware

I have a asus laptop with a 3to seagate hdd (st3000dm001) 3.5" 7200 rpm

Yesterday, I had an update from ubuntu which I installed as habits. My laptop crash as the battery was low, turned it on, if i'm right it was update from 16.04 to 18.04, I don't know if the crash occurred while the update or if it was fully done. (There were slight changes like the turn off menu with the update after reboot)

I closed my laptop, hence it slept, when I opened it again to turn it off, it was weird, wifi wouldn't turn on, shutdown item in menu in top-right hand corner  was not working hence I shut it down using 5s press on power button

When pressed the power button to turn it on few hours later, it shows the asus bios screen then restart and again and again, not showing grub.

I can start with a usb live key

the hdd spin normally I hear/feel it

I tryied to plug in in another computer, which doesn't recognize it

In my bios laptop the sata port appears empty (I plugged it off and then plugged it again)

While running a live linux I can't see it

dmesg report sata port as dummy

I had with the usb test disk : comreset failed errno : -16

I don't know what to do more...
Is my hdd dead while the head is still spining?
If it's an os problem (software side, I think about faulty mbr) would it shows up while on linux live?
What can I try?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your BIOS cannot detect the hard drive, then it's either disconnected (power or data or both) or dead. Nothing more Ubuntu can do about it.

Open the case and see if it's merely disconnected.

Comment: The thing is even I want to reinstall an OS, I can't find/see the device like not connected

Comment: Thanks I will do it, I need to find the screwdriver which is really really small, I never see one likewise before